# Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1., SQL state 07001 in SQLExecDirect

Tags: php, odbc

Im getting an error using `PHP > ODBC`

> Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access
>   Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1., SQL state 07001 in
>   SQLExecDirect

```
$sql='SELECT 
        CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,
        USERINFO.Badgenumber,
        USERINFO.Name
    FROM
        CHECKINOUT
    RIGHT JOIN
        USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID
    WHERE
        c.CHECKTIME >= #'.$dateToday.' 00:00:00# AND c.CHECKTIME <= #'.$dateToday.' 23:59:59#
    ORDER BY
        CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME DESC
    ';
```

Comment: Hi, Please post the php code, `odbc_exec()` it seems you missed something on it's parameter not the query itself.

Comment: @Roshan sorry I already fixed the error ..please see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this code by adding {ts }

```
SELECT 
        CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME,
        USERINFO.Badgenumber,
        USERINFO.Name
    FROM
        CHECKINOUT
    RIGHT JOIN
        USERINFO ON CHECKINOUT.USERID = USERINFO.USERID
    WHERE
        CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME BETWEEN  {ts '".$reqDTS."'} AND {ts '".$reqDTE."'}
    ORDER BY
        CHECKINOUT.CHECKTIME DESC
```